# Visual Studio changing my target runtime?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild

A colleague of mine has a little problem with his dev env (Win 7 + VS 2010):

We have a class librairy project which reference .net 2.0, if we build it with "Debug" and open it with Reflector, we can see "Target Runtime : 2.0..." if we build it with "Release" configuration, we can see "Target Runtime : v4.0" (and if we use it in our test server we have message error like "This assembly is built by a runtime newer than")

In the project properties I can see ".net framework 2.0" .In my .csproj, I have

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v2.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

Do you have any idea?

EDIT

here is the beginning of my .csproj

```
<Project ToolsVersion="2.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>9.0.30729</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{E7122A64-C206-47EB-A511-763FF9C9D560}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>ControlSkin3</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>ControlSkin3</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v2.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <Nonshipping>true</Nonshipping>
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <CodeAnalysisCulture>en-en</CodeAnalysisCulture>
    <TargetCulture>en-en</TargetCulture>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <GenerateSerializationAssemblies>Off</GenerateSerializationAssemblies>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v2.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <GenerateSerializationAssemblies>Off</GenerateSerializationAssemblies>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: I didn't know what it was until your comment, so no I don't use it.

Comment: Can you post the beginning of your csproj, until the itemgroup defining the references?

Comment: That's strange. You have an extra TargetFrameworkVersion in your Release Properties, but it is not related to your current problem (I tried in a project of mine and it doesn't bother). How do you start the debug and release builds? From VS? From Command Line? Do you have pre or post build events?

Comment: No pre/post build event. To start the build I do like this in VS : Build -> Configuration manager -> Select Debug or Release in the list. I'll try to have a look at the verbose output, maybe there is something there.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem where a 3.5 targeted Class Library in VS10 comes out with a Target Runtime of v4.0 in Reflector and caused problems when used in applications where the only supportedRuntime is set to v2.0.

In my case it had to do with a post-build event which de-assembles the assembly does some magic and then "assembles" it again like this:

```
call "$(DevEnvDir)..\Tools\vsvars32.bat"
ildasm "$(TargetFileName)" /out=myassembly.il /nobar /linenum 
magic.exe myassembly.il ilasm myassembly.changed.il
ilasm myassembly.changed.il /DLL /OUTPUT="$(TargetFileName)"
```

This works fine in VS2008 because the path environment variable is pointing to the v2.0 version of the framework. In VS 2010 it seems they point to the v4.0 version, so when the IL is processed it creates 4.0 code.

ilasm.exe does not have a switch to tell it to build for the v2.0 version, but is exists in specific versions for each framework version. To fix this for me I did specify the full path to the tools:

```
call "$(DevEnvDir)..\Tools\vsvars32.bat"
"%WindowsSdkDir%bin\ildasm "$(TargetFileName)" /out=myassembly.il /nobar /linenum 
magic.exe myassembly.il ilasm myassembly.changed.il
%FrameworkDir%\v2.0.50727\ilasm myassembly.changed.il /DLL /OUTPUT="$(TargetFileName)"
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but I don't use any post build event, but maybe I  didn't understand your answer

Comment: note that using `%FrameworkDir%\v2.0.50727\ilasm` works also in visual studio 2010 command-prompt, and not only in build events